# template with one explicit argument

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I try to add another template argument to the factorial example of meta programming. But the following doesn't work. What is the correct way?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int Depth>
inline void loop(T i){
    std::cout << i;
    loop<T, Depth-1>(i - 1);
}
template <typename T, int Depth>
inline void loop<T, 0>(T i){
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main(void){
    int i = 10;
    loop<int, 3>(i);
}
```

Error:

```
test4.cpp(9): error: an explicit template argument list is not allowed on this declaration
  inline void loop<T, 0>(T i){
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot partially specialize function templates. Full stop.

In C++17, you will be able to write:

```
template <typename T, int Depth>
inline void loop(T i){
    std::cout << i;
    if constexpr (Depth > 0) {
        loop<T, Depth-1>(i - 1);
    }
}
```

until then, I would propose just taking the depth as an `integral_constant` argument:

```
template <typename T>
inline void loop(T i, std::integral_constant<int, 0> ) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, int Depth>
inline void loop(T i, std::integral_constant<int, Depth> ){
    std::cout << i;
    loop(i - 1, std::integral_constant<int, Depth-1>{} );
}
```

Comment: how to call that loop? I mean what should the main function look like?

Comment: I get error if I use `int main(void){
    int i = 10; 
    loop(i, std::integral_constant<int, 3>{} );
}` and compile with g++ -std=c++14. Error is template instantiation depth exceed 900.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a helper class and its specialization to do the real work.

```
template <typename T, int Depth> struct LoopHelper
{
   static void doit(T i)
   {
      std::cout << i;
      LoopHelper<T, Depth-1>::doit(i);
   }
};

template <typename T> struct LoopHelper<T,0>
{
   static void doit(T i)
   {
      std::cout << i;
   }
};


template <typename T, int Depth>
inline void loop(T i){
   LoopHelper<T, Depth>::doit(i);
}
```

**Additional refinement**

I would recommend changing `loop` to allow deduction of `T`.

```
template <int Depth, typename T>
inline void loop(T i){
   LoopHelper<T, Depth>::doit(i);
}
```

Then, you can use:

```
int i = 10;
loop<3>(i);
```

and let `T` be deduced as `int`.

Comment: @rxu, Yes, it does. I tested it before I posted the answer.